# How to insert html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to insert the whole element into the container element however It throws some object into the DOM

JS:

```
const CONTAINER = document.getElementById('container');
let title = document.querySelector('h1').cloneNode(true);
CONTAINER.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', title);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Comment: That's because you used `insertAdjacentHTML`, but `title` is not a string value containing HTML code, it is an HTMLElementObject. Use `appendChild` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, as a one-liner:

```js
document.getElementById('container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', document.querySelector('h1').outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">This is the target container</div>
<p>Some padding text</p>
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

`title` it is an HTMLElementObject. Use appendChild instead.

```js
const CONTAINER = document.getElementById('container');
let title = document.querySelector('h1').cloneNode(true);
CONTAINER.appendChild(title);
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
<h1>Test</h1>
```